# Gettingerror: legacy-install-failure, while installing basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install Basemap using pip, however at some point it reaches the error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I do not really know what to do here, and I could not find anyone who encountered the same error. I have tried upgrading pip and setuptools, but they did not seem to help. What should I do?

P.S. I have been trying to install basemap for the past 4 days and I was not very sucessfull. If you know how to install it on MacOS, please hit me up! Thank you!

Comment: is that arrow pointing to `numpy` telling you to install numpy ?  `pip install numpy` then install `Basemap` assuming that it has that dependancy.

Comment: @D.L I assume yes. But I have numpy installed, also I have tried uninstalling it and running without it, still same error. I am kinda confused at this point.

Comment: Could you provide the complete traceback that you get when trying to install `basemap`? Note also that `basemap` does not have precompiled wheels for MacOS in PyPI at the moment; therefore, `pip` will try to install `basemap` from the source distribution (i.e. the zip file), and this will only work under certain assumptions (e.g. that you have a C compiler available, or that you define `GEOS_DIR` so that `libgeos` can be found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows:

To install `basemap` you need to download the wheel file from this path:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap)

for `python 3.10` this will be the file:

***basemap‑1.3.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl***

Then you have to go to the folder where the above mentioned `.whl` file is saved and run this command from there:

`pip install basemap‑1.3.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl`

---

For Mac OS please refer:

https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases:

Make sure you have:

```
brew install geos
brew install matplotlib
brew install numpy
brew install proj
```

Add `export GEOS_DIR="/user/local/Cellar/geos/3.10.2/"` to your .bash profile and reload it via:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
```

then in the `basemap/packages/basemap` directory

`pip3 install`

---

For Google Colab:

```
!sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.6.2
!sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
!pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap#subdirectory=packages/basemap
```

Comment: Precompiled binary wheels for Windows are now available from PyPI too, so on Windows the installation simplifies to just a pip install basemap.

Comment: `matplotlib` is not available anymore, please install / update `matplotplusplus`